# R fill in new column by filtered value by group

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, expand

I want to create new column in my `dat`, filled in by values 
satisfying a condition. So, I want to keep the `value` where where `regime == "SA"` and fill this value over the whole group in new column `vals.sa`.

This combines the `filter` and `mutate`, but I am unsure what is their correct combination? `Filter` just keeps rows satisfying condition, but how can I expand this value over all rows in a group?

My data:

```
dat <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3),
                  regime = c("SA", "B", "SA", "B", "C", "F", "SA", "D"),
                  value = c(3,5,1,2,5,6,7,8))
```

Process the data using `dplyr`

```
dat %>% 
  # group data by id
  group_by(id) %>%           
  # how to write this condition and get values instead or TRUE/FALSE?
  mutate(val.sa = regime == "SA")
```

Expected output with filled in `val.sa` value corresponding `regime == "SA"`

```
     id regime value val.sa
  <dbl> <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 SA         3      3
2     1 B          5      3
3     2 SA         1      1
4     2 B          2      1
5     2 C          5      1
6     2 F          6      1
7     3 SA         7      7
8     3 D          8      7
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use :

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(value.sa = value[regime == 'SA'])
  #OR
  #mutate(value.sa = value[match('SA', regime)])


#     id regime value value.sa
#  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>    <dbl>
#1     1 SA         3        3
#2     1 B          5        3
#3     2 SA         1        1
#4     2 B          2        1
#5     2 C          5        1
#6     2 F          6        1
#7     3 SA         7        7
#8     3 D          8        7
```

If there could be more than one `regime` in a group where it has value `"SA"`, you can select the first value using `which.max`/`match`.

```
dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(value.sa = value[which.max(regime == 'SA')])
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you alwas have only one `SA` in each group, this should run without any errors:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%             
  mutate(val.sa = value[regime == "SA"]) 
#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>      id regime value val.sa
#>   <dbl> <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1 SA         3      3
#> 2     1 B          5      3
#> 3     2 SA         1      1
#> 4     2 B          2      1
#> 5     2 C          5      1
#> 6     2 F          6      1
#> 7     3 SA         7      7
#> 8     3 D          8      7
```

otherwise, you would have to decide which `SA`-value you would like to keep. For example always keeping the maximum value:

```
dat <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3),
                  regime = c("SA", "B", "SA", "SA", "C", "F", "SA", "D"),
                  value = c(3,5,1,2,5,6,7,8))
dat
#>   id regime value
#> 1  1     SA     3
#> 2  1      B     5
#> 3  2     SA     1
#> 4  2     SA     2
#> 5  2      C     5
#> 6  2      F     6
#> 7  3     SA     7
#> 8  3      D     8

dat %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%             
  mutate(val.sa = max(value[regime == "SA"]))
#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>      id regime value val.sa
#>   <dbl> <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1 SA         3      3
#> 2     1 B          5      3
#> 3     2 SA         1      2
#> 4     2 SA         2      2
#> 5     2 C          5      2
#> 6     2 F          6      2
#> 7     3 SA         7      7
#> 8     3 D          8      7
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a new column `val.sa` first with the value in the `SA` rows equal to the values in the `value` column. Then group by `id` and `fill` down. Like this:

```
dat %>%
  mutate(val.sa = ifelse(regime == 'SA', value, NA)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  fill(val.sa)
## A tibble: 8 x 4
## Groups:   id [3]
#     id regime value val.sa
#  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1 SA         3      3
#2     1 B          5      3
#3     2 SA         1      1
#4     2 B          2      1
#5     2 C          5      1
#6     2 F          6      1
#7     3 SA         7      7
#8     3 D          8      7
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
 dat %>%
     mutate(val.sa = case_when(regime == 'SA' ~ value) %>%
     group_by(id) %>%
     fill(val.sa)
```